# Petite-Vue filtered array reactivity?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, petite-vue

I played arround with Petite-Vue and really like it. Works fine with reactivity / ui updates and helpers like "$el" and "$refs" for easy form field handling / data binding.

Now I tried to have a reactive list with updates live if backend data (gundb) changes.
UI updates work fine if I list all array entries with "v-for".

If I try to filter the array of players by one team (object property "team") the UI is initialy correct rendered, but if a players name changed the update is pushed to gundb and by listener also to players array based on PetiteVue.reative(). So all is fine, but no UI update is triggered. Item is a Proxy as needed for (petite-)vue reactivity.

So it looks like a `players.filter(...)` call break reactivity. Also tried a method and getter inside of a component and also directly by write `players.filter(...)` to the html template.

Do I missing the right way how to trigger a re-render of changed *filtered reactive array of objects*?

I have a function to sync gundb "backend" changes to Petite-Vue.reactive object

```
gunArray2vue = (gunNode, vueArray) => {
                gunNode.map().on((value, soul) => {
                    item = vueArray.find(item => item && item._ && item._['#'] === soul)
                    console.log('gunArray2vue', `soul=${soul}`, value, item)
                    
                    if(!!item && value === null) {
                        // item in VUE but seems deleted... remove from vue array...
                        console.log("ToDeleteItem", item)
                        vueArray.splice(vueArray.indexOf(item), 1)
                    } else if(!value) {
                        console.log("Ignore creation of empty object")
                        return // don't add empty object...
                    } else if(item) {   
                        //vueArray[vueArray.indexOf(item)] = value // update
                        console.log("UpdateItem")
                        item = value                // update                        
                    } else {
                        console.log("AddArrayItem")
                        vueArray.push(value)        // add new
                    }
                })
            }
```

Changed Value checked with console:
[checked change in js console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVFtq.png)

But UI isn't refreshed.
Here the code in componente

1. tested as getter / function

```
//filteredPlayers: function() {
                get filteredPlayers() {
                    if(this.form.nr || this.form.name) {
                        return this.players.filter(player =>
                            player.name.includes(this.form.name) || player.nr == this.form.nr
                        )
                    } else {
                        return this.players
                    }
                }
```

The filtering is reactive to my input field! But changed name is ignored.

And here is a simpler getter function

```
                get myPlayers() {
                    page.players
                }
```

But ui isn't updated if an item changes without refresh.
So filtering works reactive, but changed items are not detected and re-rendered.

Also tried directly to use the unfiltered PetiteVue.reactive object like that.

```
<div v-for="player in page.players">{{player.nr}} {{player.name}}</div>
```

Rendering works fine, but also not updated on change.

**Update**
Noticed during my tests today, that updates work if I directly change my original object `page.players`, but not / no more if I use a *reference* to the original reactive object?

So I can't use the reactive object by reference without loose ui reactivity for item changes?

**Update2**
Add and remove an reactive array entry works fine!
Just update an item won't work. Tested different ways to set the item object / key -> val of object. Change isn't reactive.

Function with my tests

```
                gun2arrayListener = (name, table) => {
                    console.log(`Register Listener Gun table "${name}"`)
                    DB.get(name).map().on((value, soul) => {
                        console.log("DEBUG", soul, value)
                        item = table.find(item => item?._['#'] === soul)
                        index = table.indexOf(item)
                        console.log('gun2array', `soul=${soul}`, value, item)
                        if(Object.is(item, value)) {
                            console.log("Skip unchanged item")
                        } else if(item && value === null) {
                            console.log("ToDeleteItem", item)
                            table.splice(index, 1)
                        } else if(!value) {
                            console.log("Ignore creation of empty object?!")
                        } else if(item) {   
                            console.log("UPDATE", "ARRAY", item, value)
                            // !!! CHANGES NOT REACTIVE HERE !!!
                            // !!!  method is triggered, changes looks good, but reload page needed to update UI !!!
                            //item = value
                            //TABLES[name][index] = value
                            //Object.assign(item, value)
                            //table.splice(index, 1, value)
                            //table.splice(index, 1); table.push(value)
                            for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(value)) {
                                console.log(`${key}: ${val}`)
                                //item[key] = val
                                store.players[index][key] = val
                                console.log(item)
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("AddNewGunNodeItem", value)
                            table.push(value)        // add new
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Strange... if I test reactivity from outside it works ?!

```
store.players[0].name = "BUM!"  // works as needed in function... ?!
```

I noticed gun fires the listener twice, but that should result in correct updated array object, just changed to the new value twice...

I can't prevent that, because can't compare old object (vue proxy object) with the new object (plain object without vue proxy) to skip unchanged object here. Object.is results in false because of the Proxy arround...

Comment: Please share the whole code

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your fast reply. I need to reduce the code to a simpler example for that. I thought I have missed something or it's not supported with petite-vue (has no computed feature)...

Comment: Are you using vue 2? If so, you might need to use the `set` method instead of directly mutating your reactive object. Also, use a computed method to generate your filtered items.

Comment: I use Petite-Vue

Post is updated with some code passages

I noticed the cause of my problem is that I work with the *reference* of a PetiteVue.reactive object! Thougt that should be fine, because each item is proxied by Petite-Vue.reactive ... 
Is there a way to work with a reference to an object or a sub-array of the reactive object without loose the reactivity to UI?

Comment: Finally found the problem... Looks like the 

Two small changes to the update and create listener...

Update
```
//table.splice(index, 1, value)
table.splice(index, 1, {...value})
```

insert
```
//table.push(value)
table.push({...value})
```

Looks like there was a PetiteVue.reactive Proxy around the value / item? Tested `{...value}` solved my problem... Thanks!

Comment: @pwFoo Could you please change your comment with the solution to an answer to your own question?